# Applying a Prefab's Instance's overrides in Unity3D through code (C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, editor, unity3d-editor, prefab

As of v2020.3 Unity has still not provided us with a clean API for applying a single prefab's overrides through script.

Essentially a clean one-liner to really mirror the concept of "Apply Prefab", including handling of exceptions.

This is outdated as it uses deprecated functions
https://forum.unity.com/threads/apply-changes-to-prefab-keyboard-shortcut.29251/#post-2538088

Answer (score 0):

Having fought with this for a while, the current script is as follows. Hope it serves as a basis for building a custom workflow that works for you.

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public static class Editor_Helper
{
    [MenuItem("Editor/Apply Selected Prefab &[")]
    public static void ApplySelectedPrefab()
    {
        GameObject gO = GetCurrentlySelectedObjectHierarchy();

        if (gO == null)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Selection is not a GameObject");
            return;
        }

        GameObject rootGO = PrefabUtility.GetOutermostPrefabInstanceRoot(gO);
        
        if (rootGO == null)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning(string.Format("Selected GameObject ({0}) is not part of a prefab", gO), gO);
            return;
        }

        PrefabInstanceStatus prefabInstanceStatus = PrefabUtility.GetPrefabInstanceStatus(rootGO);
        if (prefabInstanceStatus != PrefabInstanceStatus.Connected)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning(string.Format("Selected Prefab Root of {0} ({1}) has invalid status of {2}", gO, rootGO, prefabInstanceStatus), rootGO);
            return;
        }

        if (!PrefabUtility.HasPrefabInstanceAnyOverrides(rootGO, false))
        {
            Debug.LogWarning(string.Format("Selected Prefab Root of {0} ({1}) doesn't have any overrides", gO, rootGO), rootGO);
            return;
        }

        PrefabUtility.ApplyPrefabInstance(rootGO, InteractionMode.UserAction);
        AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
        
        Debug.Log(string.Format("Changes on {0} applied to {1}", gO, rootGO), rootGO);
    }

    private static GameObject GetCurrentlySelectedObjectHierarchy() => Selection.activeGameObject;
}
```